# Is there a way to import more number of amazon products using woo commerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

I am trying to build an amazon affiliate ecommerce website using wordpress. I have to manually import products(max 10) from amazon every time. Is there a way to import more number of products at a time?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use [Amazon Product Advertising API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/Welcome.html) to get products.

Import with [WP All Import](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-all-import/)
plugin + add on: [Import Products from any XML or CSV to WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-xml-csv-product-import/)
plugin.

Same authors have a $139 commercial version for WooCommerce: [WP All Import](http://www.wpallimport.com). Commercial plugin lets you automate different types of imports. E.g., to load categories into a template for a specific import.

I have written numerous plugins to load affiliate products. Use [Amazon examples](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/rest-signature.html) and save your search params to get different types of products.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this approach.